# Facebook request window title

Tags: android, facebook

I can't change the title of App Requests dialog on android. Is it possible?

Here's my code:

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("data", "some data");
    b.putString("title", "some title");
    b.putString("frictionless", "1");
    b.putString("app_id", app_id);
    WebDialog requestsDialog = (
            new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(m_parent,
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    b))
            .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
```

Why no work?

Comment: same question here and waiting for answer , but my question has another part more than the title ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437559/change-facebook-sdk-request-dialog-title-notification-title