# Change Facebook SDK request dialog title & notification title

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-requests

this question is about android ... I have been a week for now trying to display my own message as a title for the invitation/request dialog  and for the notification as well (for facebook SDK 3.0+) but i cant know how, and the facebook SDK documentation is a piece of !@#$, i must go through all the documentation from the start to know a little piece of information

here is my code

```
        final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("app_id", /*app id*/);
        parameters.putString("to", /*selected friends*/);
        parameters.putString("message", /*a message displayed to the inviter*/);
        WebDialog dialog = new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
                        this, Session.getActiveSession(), parameters)
                        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {/*what ever happens here */}
                        }).build();
        dialog.show();
```

now 2 points :

```
1- i want to set the title of the request dialog, all i can see is "app requests"
2- i want to change the message that appears in the notification for the receiver
```

and PLEASE dont tell me see the facebook documentation, it is a piece of !@#$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can actually change the message for the notification. If you can find it in the documentation, it will tell you it's not possible (at least that's what I last came across). But you can change the title for the Dialog.

```java
WebDialog dialog = new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
                    this, Session.getActiveSession(), parameters)
                    .setTitle("Whatever title you like")
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                        /*what ever happens here */
                    }}).build();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: will try this code and see if it works for me or not ... thanks in advance

Comment: setTitle function only changes the title of the dialog. How do you change the title of the notification that appears at the receiver's end ?

Comment: You can't change the title of the notification that the receiver will see. FB uses the Custom Stories to define these, you could define the way your Graph Object (used for a story) is displayed. They will also automatically be translated by FB.