# How to change Facebook web dialog titile, not to be App Requests?

Tags: android

I already find questions about this, but no answers. No one answered to this user: [Change Facebook SDK request dialog title & notification title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437559/change-facebook-sdk-request-dialog-title-notification-title)

Can anyone tell me how to change title on Facebook request dialog(for invining friends) to something else (something which will have more sense in my game)?  Defoult title is App Requests. Is there any parameter to pass with request or what? For now my params only contains message...

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "Something...");
        showDialogWithoutNotificationBar(params);
```

And fnc showDialogWithoutNotificationBar:

```
    private void showDialogWithoutNotificationBar(Bundle params) {  

     dialog = new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this, Session.getActiveSession(), params).
            setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {

                if (error != null && !(error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException)) {
                        Log.v("showDialogWithoutNotificationBar", "network_error");
                }

                else 
                {  
                    Toast.makeText(EndlessFinishActivity.this,
                            "Request sent",  
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                dialog = null;
                dialogAction = null;
                dialogParams = null;
            }        
        }).build();

        Window dialog_window = dialog.getWindow();
        dialog_window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        dialogParams = params;
        dialog.show();          
}
```

I'm not allowed to post images here so I m sorry, but I hope you understand my question...